# Is there a well known function which has $7, 8, 21$ among its first values?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

In other words, function similar to the exponential one or Gamma or anything that has $7, 8, 21$ in its first values (not necessarily $7$ for $x = 1$), but say like:

$f(x) = 7; $

$f(x + 1) = 8;$

$f(x + 2) = 21;$

where $x$ is natural number, ideally the function should give such results as above for the first numbers: $\{1, \ldots, 10\}$.

Also: the function also produces only natural numbers and other primes, not just $7$.

Comment: See the relevant entry in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C+8%2C+21&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Does $f(x)=6 x^2 - 17 x + 18$ count?

Comment: A137823: 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 21, 61, 62, 183, 547, 548, 1641,...

Answer (score 4):

The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) does give almost forty results for the search `7, 8, 21`, but you did say "well known." This suggests you want what the OEIS calls a "core" sequence. I amend my search to `7, 8, 21 keyword:core` and... get no results at all.

What about a "nice" sequence? I try `7, 8, 21 keyword:nice` and get only [one result](https://oeis.org/A215888): numbers $N$ such that $$2^N - 1 - \sum_{\textrm{prime } p < N} 2^p$$ is prime. For example, $2^7 - 1 - (2^2 + 2^3 + 2^5) = 128 - 1 - (4 + 8 + 32) = 127 - 44 = 83$. Does that do it for you?